# Javascript, UI: Looking for a good list explorer component

Tags: javascript, user-interface, request, components, explorer

Think Windows Explorer's 'Details' view.  I need to output my database to this view.

Here's what I need:

- Columns should be horizontally resizeable.
- Columns should be able to be reordered via. dragging and dropping their headers.
- I need to be able to sort the data by a given column, like when its header is clicked on (with toggling for ascending/descending order).
- It can be a jQuery plug-in, if you know of one that does this.
- Preferably free.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it can be 
http://www.sencha.com/products/js/

for example http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html